# Enable the intrinsic sitename tag blacklist on older sites

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, tags, stack-exchange, moderation

I was going through the "blacklisted user input" page on Physics, and I noticed that the standard intrinsic tag blacklist that stops users from entering the site name as a tag (e.g. `^physics$`) was missing. Looking in to it, many older sites like [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/?as=1), [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/?as=1), [Stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), [Security](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/we-dont-need-the-security-tag) don't have this blacklist. All new sites (regardless of the beta status) have it (try to submit a blank question with the site domain name as a tag and it'll give you an error).

Could the tag blacklist be enabled on all sites?

Comment: I'm not sure [stackoverflow] should be blacklisted from SO. It's pretty popular.

Comment: @Mat: of course, there are cases where it doesn't apply. (though the [stackoverflow.com] tag needs baleeting). But places like Physics.SE certainly don't need such tags.

Comment: Oh. I hadn't encountered [stackoverflow.com]... looks like a mess. (Agreed your proposal makes sense. I'm not too hot about the [database-administration] tag on DBA.SE either, now that I see it exists.)

Comment: @Mat: In fact the SO tag pointed to [SO.com] in its excerpt and wiki, I edited it out.

Comment: Also note that, on this very site, the [tag:meta] tag is used (at least according to its description) for questions specifically about this site, 
<https://meta.stackexchange.com>. Since the meaning of the tag is not subjective or dependent on any other tags, the [tag:meta] tag does not qualify as a [meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) (though I think it *is* a **meta tag**). It also identifies an on-topic subset of questions. (Unfortunately, people also use it to tag questions pertaining to *other sites'* metas, so it still might need to die...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is handled on a case-by-case basis. If your site has a term that can apply to *all* questions on the site and folks are persistent about trying to use it as a tag, post a request on your meta and we'll mark it as intrinsic.