# Is it possible to find out which are intrinsic tags for a given site?

Tags: support, tags, migration

The post [Drop or change automatic migration-rejection based on non-existing tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210532) discusses some issues related to rejected migrations. As I learned there, one of the factors influencing this is whether some of the tags on the migrated question are among the *intrinsic tags* on the target site. However, I do not know how to find out which tags are intrinsic for a given site. (Which means that there might be situations where I might flag a question for migration without knowing whether or not the migration would be rejected.)

**Question:** Is it possible to find out in some way which tags are intrinsic for a given site? If this is not possible for regular user, do at least moderators for a given site have access to this information?

---

Here is a quote from Shog9's answer to
[Drop or change automatic migration-rejection based on non-existing tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210532#215921):

> Mad Scientist's comment reminded me that it may not be well-known that certain tags are considered "intrinsic" to a site... For instance, "math" and "mathematics" on Mathematics, or tex and latex on Tex.
>
> An intrinsic tag never appears on any question on a site. If you try to add it, the system will prevent you from doing so, just as with a blacklisted tag... *However*, if you try to migrate a question with an intrinsic tag to the same site, it will be allowed (and the question will merely be tagged [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged). This covers the common cases where a tag exists on one site while being blacklisted on another.

Comment: My reading from Shog's answer is that intrinsic tags make no difference at all and simply get removed on migration.... or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @Cai A migration which is done by regular users (not by moderators) is rejected can be rejected based on the tags. It is not rejected: a) If some of the tags exists on the target site; b) if some of the tags is an intrinsic tag on the target site. (These restrictions are not for migrations done by moderators, only for migrations which are done by regular users through off-topic dialog by choosing site which is among migration paths.)

Comment: I think that usually those tags are blacklisted, so you can check it by trying to create the tag on the site (without really doing it of course). If you get an error message, the tag is blacklisted, otherwise it's not. For example, Stack Overflow won't let you create [programming] and Super User won't let you create [computer]. Even if you don't have the privilege to create tags, it will give you an error message when you enter the tag if it's blacklisted and only when you try to submit the question if it's not blacklisted.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I agree that this is a possibility how to find out whether a tag is *blacklisted*. But not every blacklisted tag is also intrinsic tag.

Comment: @DonaldDuck also requires you to have 150 rep on the target site.

Comment: @Helmar What happens at 150 rep?

Comment: @Helmar If you meant privilege to create tags, it is at 150 reputation points *on [beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/beta-sites/info)*. On graduated sites is seems to be at 1000 reputation points. (At least the ones I checked.) Strangely enough, here on meta.SE [it is at 500 reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is, as far as I'm aware, no way for regular users to see intrinsic tags<sup>*</sup>. Moderators can see intrinsic tags in the same place as blocked tags though (labelled as "Intrinsic Tag" on the *Blocklisted User Input* page, visible at /admin/blocklist).

For example, on Graphic Design I see (redacted other blocked stuff)...

> [image]

The block is a regex pattern, in this case `^` just means the beginning of a string and `$` means the end of a string, so the pattern matches only "graphics" itself, and not anything *containing* "graphics".

<sup>*</sup> It's stated [in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181772/307988) that all newer sites have the domain added as an intrinsic tag (I did test a few and was unable to add the tag, but that only proves they are blocked), although [Shog says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218532/307988) it is handled on a case-by-case basis, so I'm not sure that we can rely on that.